# Using MVC 4 & WebAPI, how do I redirect to an alternate service endpoint from within a custom filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Thanks for looking.

This is a trivial task when using a normal (not WebAPI) action filter as I can just alter the filterContext.Result property like so:

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, {"action", "Index" } });
```

Unfortunately, I have to use `HttpActionContext` for WebAPI, so I can not access `filterContext.Result`.

So what should I do in place of that?  I have the filter set up and it does execute at the appropriate time, I just don't know how to make it prevent execution of the requested service endpoint and instead point to a different one.

Here is my controller:

```
[VerifyToken]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    #region Public
        public List<DAL.Product.CategoryModel> ProductCategories(GenericTokenModel req)
        {
            return HelperMethods.Cacheable(BLL.Product.GetProductCategories, "AllCategories");
        }

        public string Error() //This is the endpoint I would like to reach from the filter!
        {
            return "Not Authorized";
        }
    #endregion Public

    #region Models
        public class GenericTokenModel
        {
            public string Token { get; set; }
        }
    #endregion Models
}
```

Here is my filter:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using ActionFilterAttribute = System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute;

namespace Web.Filters
{
    public class VerifyTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {
            dynamic test = filterContext.ActionArguments["req"];
            if (test.Token != "foo")
            {
                //How do I redirect from here??

            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in my case was simply to change the `Response` property of the `filterContext` rather than to redirect to a different endpoint.  This achieved the desired result.

Here is the revised filter:

```
public class VerifyTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {
            dynamic test = filterContext.ActionArguments["req"];
            if (test.Token != "foo")
            {
                filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```